# Algorithm using DFS

Tags: depth-first-search

im trying to solve this, its stuck in a loop but i cant understand why. I think i might need to add some more conditions and i have looked others people's code but they seem too complicated.

```
    function solve(m, s, x, y) {        
        if (x == 9 && m[x][y] == "1") 
        {return;} //if last row, found door
    
    
        if (m[x+1][y] == "1") { //down
            s.push([x+1] + ", " + [y]);
            solve(m, s, x+1, y);
        }
    
        if (m[x][y+1] == "1") { //left
            s.push([x] + ", " + [y+1]);
            solve(m, s, x, y+1);
        }
    
        if (m[x][y-1] == "1") { //right
            s.push([x] + ", " + [y-1]);
            solve(m, s, x, y-1);
        }
    
        if (matrix[x-1][y] == "1") {  //up
            s.push([x-1] + ", " + [y]);
            solve(m, s, x-1, y);
        }
        s.pop(); //if bad path with no end
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @Aldert yes but i am not sure how to fix, am currently looking at an answer here

Comment: Handy link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685952/generate-maze-with-path-of-specified-length/53690497#53690497

Comment: Please add a programming-language tag, and post [mre], including hard-coded test data. Consider using meaningful parameters names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't mark which cells you have visited, and so you will revisit the same cell again, leading to a non-ending back-and-forth moment between coordinates 4,8 and 4,9.

One way to solve that, is to leave a trace in the matrix with another value, like value 2:

```
    // ...
    if (x == 9 && matrix[x][y] == "1") {    
        { return; } //if last row, found door

    matrix[x][y] = 2; // mark as visited <-- add this
    // ...
```

Some other issues:

- You should implement backtracking in way that the caller knows whether the recursive search was successful or not. So let your function return something that indicates this, like a boolean. Only when that return value is true, exit. Otherwise, the alternative directions should still be tried, and if no alternatives exist, the pop should happen with a return of false. Also the base cases should return true or false.
- The range checks should not be done with literals like `9`, but be dynamic, so they check the actual size of the input array.

```js
let stack = [];
let matrix = [  
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],        
             ];

function solve(matrix, stack, x, y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= matrix.length || y < 0 || y >= matrix[0].length) {
        return false;
    }

    if (x == matrix.length - 1 && matrix[x][y] == "1") {    
        return true; //if last row, found door
    }
    matrix[x][y] = 2; // mark as visited

    if (matrix[x+1][y] == "1") { //down
        stack.push([x+1] + ", " + [y]);
        if (solve(matrix, stack, x+1, y)) return true;
    }

    if (matrix[x][y+1] == "1") { //left
        stack.push([x] + ", " + [y+1]);
        if (solve(matrix, stack, x, y+1)) return true;
    }

    if (matrix[x][y-1] == "1") { //right
        stack.push([x] + ", " + [y-1]);
        if (solve(matrix, stack, x, y-1)) return true;
    }

    if (matrix[x-1][y] == "1") {  //up
        stack.push([x-1] + ", " + [y]);
        if (solve(matrix, stack, x-1, y)) return true;
    }
    stack.pop(); //if bad path with no end
    return false;
}


function detectStart(matrix, stack) {
    for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
        if (matrix[0][y] === 1) {
            stack.push([0] + ", " + [y]);
            solve(matrix, stack, 0, y);
            console.log(stack);
            return;
        }
    }
}

detectStart(matrix, stack);
```

Some other remarks:

- it is a bit strange that you compare matrix values with strings, while you initialise the matrix with numeric values.
- You could avoid some code repetition and do the check for 1 in the cell and the subsequent `push` at the *start* of the function, instead of doing that *before* the (recursive) call.

Comment: i have been all day working with this  and one line its all it took, thank you so much. T_T

Comment: Hey Im still debugging with that line, and now i realized it will sometimes block access to other cells, and only half the path will be checked. Not sure if u got any suggestions

Comment: If it would block access to other cells, then you should find the path on backtracking to that cell. Can you give an example grid with this problem?

Comment: I added some points to my answer.

Comment: Thats well thought! i was considering of returning booleans but was unsure if it would make a big difference. Thanks!!

Comment: @trincot, Respected trincot, why doesn't your recursive command-function ```solve()``` consider the visit of such cells in that matrix, consisting of ```0``` and ```1```, as [3][2], [3][3] and [2][3]?

Comment: It does visit those cells, but as they don't lead to a solution, they result in `false` to be returned, and those cells eventually get popped from the stack, and then the execution goes to an alternative route, so that the stack grows again. Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(stack));` as the first line in the function, and you will see the evolution of the stack during the run.

Comment: @trincot, Respected trincot, is the main task of that recursive command-function ```solve()``` traversing from ```0``` row to ```5``` row of the matrix?

Comment: Yes, this is according to the comment in the Asker's code: "//if last row, found door". So the goal is to find a path to any 1-cell in the last row. According to `detectStart`, where 0 is passed for the row index, the path may start in any 1-cell in the top row, i.e. the row with index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of the current problem, created by **Mr. trincot**. The implementation is in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=6;
vector<vector<int>> matrix={{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
vector<vector<int>> visited(maximumSize, vector<int>(maximumSize, 0));
vector<tuple<int, int>> path;
void showContentVector2D(vector<vector<int>>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<input[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout<<input[i][j]<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
void showContentVectorTuple(vector<tuple<int, int>>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<get<0>(input[i])<<" : "<<get<1>(input[i])<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
void dfs(int indexX, int indexY)
{
    if(indexX<0 || indexX==matrix.size() || indexY<0 || indexY==matrix[0].size())
    {
        return;
    }
    if(indexX==(matrix.size()-1) && (matrix[indexX][indexY]==1))
    {
        visited[indexX][indexY]=1;
        auto indices=make_tuple(indexX, indexY);
        path.push_back(indices);
        return;
    }
    visited[indexX][indexY]=1;
    auto indices=make_tuple(indexX, indexY);
    path.push_back(indices);
    if(visited[indexX+1][indexY]==0)
    {
        if(matrix[indexX+1][indexY]==1)
        {
            dfs(indexX+1, indexY);
            if(visited[indexX+1][indexY])
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(visited[indexX-1][indexY]==0)
    {
        if(matrix[indexX-1][indexY]==1)
        {
            dfs(indexX-1, indexY);
            if(visited[indexX-1][indexY])
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(visited[indexX][indexY-1]==0)
    {
        if(matrix[indexX][indexY-1]==1)
        {
            dfs(indexX, indexY-1);
            if(visited[indexX][indexY-1])
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(visited[indexX][indexY+1]==0)
    {
        if(matrix[indexX][indexY+1]==1)
        {
            dfs(indexX, indexY+1);
            if(visited[indexX][indexY+1])
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    for(int i=0; i<matrix.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(matrix[0][i]==1)
        {
            dfs(0, i);
        }
    }
    cout<<"visited <- "<<endl;
    showContentVector2D(visited);
    cout<<endl<<"matrix <- "<<endl;
    showContentVector2D(matrix);
    cout<<endl<<"path <- "<<endl;
    showContentVectorTuple(path);
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
visited <- 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

matrix <- 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 

path <- 
0 : 1
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 1
3 : 0
4 : 0
5 : 0
```

Comment: @trincot, Hello, respected Mr. trincot. Here is the solution, provided by you, with the implementation in C++, if you are interested.