How to implement an A* algorithm in an unknown maze?
I’m working on a project involving the A* algorithm to navigate through an unknown maze. The maze is randomly generated with walls, and the goal is to reach a specific target node. However, I’m encountering several issues, including getting stuck in dead-ends and failing to find the optimal path. Here are the details and constraints of my problem:
The maze is randomly generated, with walls placed randomly throughout. I have no prior knowledge of the maze layout. At any given point, I only know the distance to the target from the current position and the adjacent nodes (neighbors) alongside their respective distances from the target node. I am using the Manhattan distance heuristic for estimating the cost to reach the target. The cost from one node to an adjacent node is always 1. The algorithm maintains a priority queue (open set) sorted by the f-score (g + h) and a closed set to track explored nodes to avoid re-exploring them. The algorithm should find a path to the target node and, if it encounters a dead-end, it should backtrack and explore alternative paths. The path should be optimal, i.e., the shortest path to the target.
The issues I am facing include the algorithm sometimes getting stuck in a dead-end and failing to backtrack correctly to explore other potential paths, and in some cases, the algorithm fails to find the target node even when it is reachable.
Here's the pseudocode with my current logic:
function explore(state):
Initialize gScore as an empty map to store the cost of getting to each node
Initialize closedSet as an empty set to track explored nodes
Initialize openSet as a priority queue, with nodes sorted by their f-score

    Set startNode to the current location of state
    Set startDist to the distance from the current location to the target
    Add startNode to openSet with its startDist
    Set gScore[startNode] to 0
    
    while openSet is not empty:
        current = the node from openSet with the lowest f-score
        currentNodeId = the ID of current node
    
        if currentNodeId is already in closedSet:
            skip to the next iteration
        
        if state.getDistanceToTarget() is 0:
            return  # Found the target
    
        Add currentNodeId to closedSet
        
        if state.getCurrentLocation() is not currentNodeId:
            moved = false
            for each neighbor in state.getNeighbours():
                if neighbor.nodeID is currentNodeId:
                    state.moveTo(currentNodeId)
                    moved = true
                    break
            if not moved:
                continue  # Skip if no valid neighbor found
        
        for each neighborStatus in state.getNeighbours():
            neighborId = neighborStatus.nodeID
    
            if neighborId is in closedSet:
                continue  # Ignore already explored neighbors
    
            tentativeGScore = gScore[currentNodeId] + 1  # All moves have equal cost of 1
    
            if tentativeGScore is less than gScore[neighborId] or neighborId is not in openSet:
                gScore[neighborId] = tentativeGScore
                Add neighborId to openSet with f-score as tentativeGScore + neighborStatus.distanceToTarget
    
    print "Exploration complete. Did not find the target."

function fScore(node, gScore):
return node.distanceToTarget() + gScore\[node.nodeID\] if node.nodeID is in gScore else infinity

Ideally, the program will be able to explore, and if it reaches a dead end, be able to backtrack, however, I feel like I am missing something. Or is A* even designed to work within the constraints of this project?
Many thanks for your help!

Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685952/generate-maze-with-path-of-specified-length/53690497#53690497 if it solves your problem, please upvote

"The maze is randomly generated,"  How exactly?  Do you ensure that there is feasible solution?  I use two methods: binary tree produces simple easily solved mazes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Simple_algorithms
recursive division produces more complex mazes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method

You can take a look at my C++ code to solve a maze using A* at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Explore

Why do you provide pseudo code? You have a pseudo code interpreter on which you run this code?
